# File count works only if 1 directory

Tags: linux, command-line

.
Alias command for counting Files:

```
alias f="clear ; ls -1v -w9 -plxhSs --format=single-column --group-directories-first ; tput setaf 4 ; tput sgr0 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo "/" ; tput sgr0 ; printf "%10d%s"    ` ls -qp | grep -c / `  ' dirs       '    ` ls -qp | grep -vc /  ` ' reg.files       '    `ls -1 | wc -l `  ' files current dir.' ; echo ' ' ; tput setaf 3 ; printf "%10d%s"    ` ls -ap | egrep "^\..*/$" | wc -l `  ' dirs hidden'     ` ls -ap | grep -v / | egrep "^\." | wc -l `    ' reg.files hidden'     ` ls -a | grep -v / | egrep "^\." | wc -l  `    ' files current dir. hidden' ; echo ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; printf "%10d%s"    ` find . -type d | wc -l  `  ' dirs       '     ` find . -type f | wc -l `    ' reg.files       '     `  find . | wc -l  `    ' files recursive' ; echo ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; pwd | tr '\n' '\000' ; tput sgr0 ; echo '/' | tr '\n' ' ' ; tput setaf 13 ; echo '+ recursive' "
```

Above `f` command works fine in first directory with Ubuntu 20.04.3
Above `f` command = File count as alias, example output:

```
         8 dirs                6 reg.files               14 files current dir. 
         2 dirs hidden         2 reg.files hidden         4 files current dir. hidden 
        15 dirs               74 reg.files               89 files recursive
```

But then change directory with cd ..

And run command `f` again
And file count in new directory is same as old directory.

How come?
Why is File Count data from old directory
displaying the old data in the new current directory?

--

Comment: Many parts of your command get evaluated *when the alias is defined*. It's a matter of quoting. Invoke `alias` to see what you have defined. [Build a function instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618).

Comment: [Obligatory "do not parse `ls`" link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). :)

Comment: Please clarify.  Kamil typed Obligatory "do not parse ls" _  Confirmed that this ```ls``` code gave the wrong file count ```ls -1 | wc -l``` but this code gave the correct file count ```ls -1qi  | grep -o '^ *[0-9]*' | wc -l``` How to create problem files? use ```touch 'a b' 'a  b' a$'\xe2\x80\x82'b a$'\xe2\x80\x83'b a$'\t'b a$'\n'b``` see page ```https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead``` Please clarify. "do not parse ls".

Comment: What to clarify? I have given you a link to a quite big article. Additionally you have found a question where several people try to convince the asker who disagrees with the article. Don't expect me to outrun all this in a comment. Your original code was flawed for sure, this means you did not know the limitations of `ls`. Now you know. The link served its purpose of spreading knowledge. You modified your `ls` invocation, so now it circumvents(?) the limitations. It may be that counting files this way is a case where parsing `ls` works reliably; in general however parsing `ls` is bad practice.